# Strange behaviour of QCombobox::setItemData function

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I was working with a simple class derived(publicly) from `QComboBox` and noticed a strange behaviour of `setItemData` function:

a simple example:

```
QFont font;
font.setItalic(true);
setItemData(0, font, Qt::FontRole);
```

I was sure that this had to change the font of the first element in combobox to italic. But it does NOTHING.
I was more surprised when this code works porperly in this combination:

```
setEditable(true);  //setting my derived class editable changes the situation
QFont font;
font.setItalic(true);
setItemData(0, font, Qt::FontRole);
```

Moreover, if I run my application(which uses my custom combobox class) giving style option from terminal f.e. `-style plastique` then everything works properly, without setting combobox editable.

I couldn't find anything said about this in documentation. 
Does anybody have idea what is the reason of all this?

Here is the source code:
.h file:

```
class ComboBoxWrapper : public QComboBox
{
  Q_OBJECT;

public:
  ComboBoxWrapper(QWidget* parent = 0);

  const QString& getDefaultValue() const;
  void setDefaultValue(const QString& defaultValue);

private:
    QString defaultValue_;

};
```

And here is .cpp:

```
ComboBoxWrapper::ComboBoxWrapper(QWidget* parent)
  : QComboBox(parent)
{
  setAutoFillBackground(true);
}

const QString& ComboBoxWrapper::getDefaultValue() const
{
  return defaultValue_;
}

void ComboBoxWrapper::setDefaultValue(const QString& defaultValue)
{
  int index = findText(defaultValue);
  if(-1 == index)
  { /// current value is invalid.
    defaultValue_.clear();
    Q_ASSERT(false);
  }    

  defaultValue_ = defaultValue;
  QFont font = QApplication::font();
  font.setItalic(true);

  setEditable(true);  //setItemData doesn't work without this trick
  setItemData(index, font, Qt::FontRole);
  setEditable(false);
}
```

Comment: Hm, this works just fine to me (Qt 4.8, Windows).

Comment: Show the source of your derived class.

Comment: I have updated question...See the source code above.